# how do I use postgres dblink in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, dblink

I want to use postgres dblink from hibernate. Is it possible to open, execute and close dblink queries from hibernate.If yes then is there any example?

Comment: Using a [foreign data wrapper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html) is probably easier to use because the appear like regular tables to the obfuscation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem also occured for me.Following helped me:
[Connecting multiple database with hibernate](http://java.dzone.com/articles/connecting-multiple-databases)